# nodeBuilder() / NodeBuilder - cannot resolve symbol - Elastic Search Java API (On Android)

Tags: java, android, apache, elasticsearch

I added the Gradle dependency, `compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.2.1'`.

I got a list of warnings when the Gradle build was synced.

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

But the Gradle build was successful. Now I get an error at `nodeBuilder()` or `NodeBuilder`. The error is: `Cannot resolve symbol`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch is hosted on Maven central. In your Maven Project, you can define which ElasticSearch version you want to use in your pom.xml file as shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>0.90.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Android Studio doesn't use Maven as its builder; it uses Gradle instead. So try adding this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.90.3'
}
```